# Serverless Framework not getting localfiles

Tags: aws-glue, serverless-framework

I got a problem regarding Serverless Framework, i want to create a glue job. But when creating resource i can only choose a s3 path. Why cant i choose a local path in my repository? is this a limitation inside Serverless or am i setting up things incorrectly

Anybody got a tip for how to solve this. I know that serverless-glue plugin exist but it's not implemented in a way that i can use it correctly.

Here is the Glue example

```
resources:
   Resources:
     # Glue Job for initial load
     InitialLoadJobNpsResponses:
       Type: AWS::Glue::Job   
       Properties:
         Role: !Ref GlueJobRole
         Description: Job created with CloudFormation  
         DefaultArguments:
           "--TARGET_DYNAMODB_NAME": '{target dynamo name}'
           "--TARGET_AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER": '{my new account id}'
           "--TARGET_ROLE_NAME": 'my-role-cross'
           "--TARGET_REGION": 'eu-west-1'
           "--SOURCE_DYNAMODB_NAME": '{source dynamo name}'
           "--WORKER_TYPE": 'G.1X'
           "--NUM_WORKERS": 5
         Command:   
           Name: glueetl
           PythonVersion: 3
           ScriptLocation: Glue_Jobs/my-script.py
         ExecutionProperty:   
           MaxConcurrentRuns: 1
```

the Glue_Jobs/my-script.py dont work for me. This is a local path inside my folders of the repository

Answer (score 0):

It is due to AWS limitations.
You can find it on Glue::Job.Command properties [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-job-jobcommand.html#cfn-glue-job-jobcommand-scriptlocation)

An easy way to fix this would be to upload file to s3 during deployment and use the uploaded file through your serverless config.

Comment: Issue with uploading is that i create the S3 bucket in this serverless file aswell. So uploading should be possible right ?

Comment: @MarcusLagerstedt Your first deployment will create the S3 bucket. Next deployments might push files to your bucket.